# jsTree checkbox plugin error

Tags: jquery, plugins, checkbox, jstree

I have a jsTree with checkboxes that shows up just fine. I can open
and close the nodes, check and uncheck the checkboxes, etc.

The problem comes in when I try to get all the nodes that have been
checked. Below I list all the ways I have tried, along with the error
messages I get when I try each one.

```
$.tree.plugin.checkbox.get_checked($.tree.reference("#smuDomains"));
$.tree is undefined

$.jstree.plugin.checkbox.get_checked($.jstree.reference("#smuDomains"));
$.jstree.plugin.checkbox is undefined

$.tree.plugins.checkbox.get_checked($.tree.reference("#smuDomains"));
$.tree is undefined

$.jstree.plugins.checkbox.get_checked($.jstree.reference("#smuDomains"));
$.jstree.plugins is undefined
```

The second one ($.jstree.plugin.checkbox) seems to be getting the
closest to working, but it doesn't seem to like the "checkbox"
reference. Should it be check_box or something different?

This is the code I use to init the tree:

```
$.jstree._themes = "../script/css/jstree/themes/";
$("#smuDomains").jstree({
    core : {}, 
    themes : {
        theme : "classic",
        dots : true,
        icons : true, 
        url : false
    },  
    json_data : {
        ajax : {
            url : "[the url]",
            datatype : "json",
            data : function(n) {
                return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 };
            },
            plugins : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui", "checkbox"]
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: Sure all the brackets are closed?

Comment: Yes, all the brackets are there, I just didn't do as good a job copying and pasting as I should have done. The tree works flawlessly. It's only when I try to make a call to get_checked that I run into the undefined errors.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this code to get checked boxes just before submit the form :

```
jQuery('#myForm').submit(function() {
    jQuery('#mytree .jstree-checked').each(function () {
        var node = jQuery(this);
        var id = node.attr('id');
        var node_parent = node.parents('li:eq(0)');
        var pid = node_parent.attr('id');

        jQuery("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "treenode").val(id).appendTo("#mytree");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

$('#tree').jstree('get_checked')

Answer (score 0):

one of the issues with get_checked is that it will stop at parent nodes that are checked.

We ended up going with something like this:

$('#idOfDivContainingTree .jstree-checked')

There is a risk of this not working with future versions of jsTree as it is dependent on the implementation

Comment: I haven't tested it myself, but if you look at the jsTree docs for the Checkbox Plugin, you will see that get_checked has a "get_all" boolean parameter which is supposed to return all checked nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

checked_nodes  = $("#smuDomains").jstree("get_checked", null, true);

$.each(checked_nodes, function(k, n) {

```
node = $(n);
alert("name: "+node.attr("name")); //show each one of the nodes names
```

});

if you want just the selected nodes, you can have:

selected_nodes  = $("#smuDomains").jstree("get_selected", null, true);

hope it helps